# Infinite Intersection of Sets General Proof Strategy

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that I want to show that an infinite intersection is equal to some set.

> $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (f(n),g(n)) = [c,d] \; \; \; f(n),g(n),c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

The general strategy would be to prove the two inclusions of the sets. When showing that the closed set is a subset of the intersection set, it is relatively intuitive in most cases. However, the proof becomes a bit more involved when showing the intersection set is a subset of the closed set.

Without getting into a specific problem for academic reasons, what would be a general approach to showing that an element from the intersections is in the closed set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show that $\bigcap X_i = Y$, I would break it up in the following two parts:

- Show that if $y\in Y$, then $y\in X_i$ for every $i$.
- Show that if $y\notin Y$, then there is some $i$ such that $y\notin X_i$.

This proves that $\bigcap X_i=Y$, pretty much immediately from the definition of an intersection.

---

In your particular example, this comes down to showing that

- $f(n)<c$ and $g(n)>d$ for every $1\leq n<\infty$, and
- for any $c'<c$ there is some $n$ such that $f(n)\geq c'$, and
- for any $d'>d$ there is some $n$ such that $g(n)\leq d'$.

Comment: What if I want to prove it using the double inclusion method? Picking in element in the intersections and trying to prove that it's in the closed set.

Comment: That's basically what the second bullet point says, if you write it as its [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): "Show that if $y\in X_i$ for every $i$, then $y\in Y$." I personally find it easier to prove it the way I did, since it can sometimes be difficult to pinpoint exactly when $y\in X_i$ for every $i$ (especially by more complicated intersections).

Comment: When trying to find some $i$ where $y \notin X_i$ is it sufficeint to give a specific example of $y$ and $i$?

Comment: Any single $i$ will suffice, whether finding it explicitly or by only proving its existence. The $y$ must be arbitrary, though: for *any* $y\notin Y$ you have to find *some* $i$ such that $y\notin X_i$. This $i$ may depend on $y$, if necessary.